# 'nl' was not declared in this scope (el "nl" me pasa con las otras variables tambien)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;



double datos(){
    

    double nl=0;//Numero Libras
    double no=0;//Numero Onzas
    cout <<"Ingrese el numero de libras a convertir"<<endl;
    cin >>nl;
    cout << "Ingrese el numero de onzas a convertir"<<endl;
    cin >>no;
    return 0;
}
    
double conversion(double& xn,double& yn){
    double kgc=0;//Kilogramos convertidos
    double gmc=0;//Gramos convertidos
    kgc= xn/2.2046;
    gmc=((yn*16.0)/2.2046)/1000;
    return 0;
    cout<<kgc<<gmc<<endl;
}
        
double resultados(double& xc, double& yc){
    cout<<""<<xc<<endl;
    cout<<""<<yc<<endl;
    return 0;
}
            
        
            
int main() {
    
    datos();
    conversion(nl, no);
    resultados(kgc, gcm);
    getch();
    return 0;
                
}
```

Estos son los problemas
error: 'nl' was not declared in this scope

40:17: error: 'no' was not declared in this scope

41:13: error: 'kgc' was not declared in this scope

41:18: error: 'gcm' was not declared in this scope

Comment: El error que indicas está en líneas de código que no has compartido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las funciones solo pueden ver las variables declaradas en su ámbito (scope) , o sea, dentro de la función, o las variables globales (las declaradas fuera de la función).
Así que,  `nl` i `no`, solo son visibles dentro la función `datos`, y `kgc` y `gcm` dentro de `conversion`.
Cuando en main haces:

```
    conversion(nl, no);
    resultados(kgc, gcm);
```

No conoce esas variables. Para solucionarlo, puedes declararlas como globales, o sea, en el `main` en vez de en `datos`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de mucha ayuda